# System Settings package

Tags: 11.04, package-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identify package by window?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96421/identify-package-by-window)

What is the package behind the System Settings power menu?

Comment: Are you referring to ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: @enzotib, I am.

Comment: I cannot understand why my answer, given before, is not accepted. You don't ask for power preferences, do you ask? No problem anyway :)

Comment: @enzotib, I'm sorry, it's because the answer is simply more informative. I don't care about the power manager part, but what I found useful was the commands that allows you to see the package behind the application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Package for gnome-power-preferences is `gnome-power-manager`. 
The Package for gnome-control-center is `gnome-control-center`

```
 $dpkg -S /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
 gnome-control-center: /usr/bin/gnome-control-center

 $dpkg -S /usr/bin/gnome-power-preferences 
 gnome-power-manager: /usr/bin/gnome-power-preferences
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be `gnome-control-center`, I think.